# Airplane mode in HTC devices (Android)

Tags: android, settings, airplane-mode

I am trying to make a simple airplane mode toggle app for android. I am able to turn the airplane mode ON but when I toggle it off, the mobile network is not turning back ON on my HTC Thunderbolt (Android 2.3.4). wifi is working fine. Wifi and Cellular both turn back on when I test on my Samsung device. I am using the following code:

```
Adapted from Controlling Airplane Mode:

// read the airplane mode setting
boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(
      getContentResolver(), 
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;

// toggle airplane mode
Settings.System.putInt(
      getContentResolver(),
      Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);

// Post an intent to reload
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state", !isEnabled);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```